# How do I find the minium value in a column after a specified date?

Tags: mysql, date, minimum

I want to find the minimum value in a column, but only if the date in the row is greater than a specified date.  I am using this query:

```
select
T.`teamId`,
T. `teamName` as winnerName,
X.teamid,
X.teamName as loserName,
date_format(`gameDate`,"%M %D") as date,
`IMPmargin` as MinIMPs
FROM `vichill_games-2` G
join `vichill_teams-2` as T on (G.winner = T.`teamid`)
join `vichill_teams-2` as X on (G.loser = X.`teamid`) 
WHERE  `IMPmargin` = (SELECT MIN(NULLIF(`IMPmargin`, 0)) FROM `vichill_games-2` WHERE `gameDate` > "2014-10-01" )
```

The query returns:

```
teamId  winnerName  teamid  loserName   date          MinIMPs
22      Boyd          26    Ellis      October 1st  14
28      Wolford       27    Ogan       October 15th 14
22      Boyd          27    Ogan       October 1st  14
```

The gameDate test is seen to some extent.  If I make the date later than the date of any game, then nothing is returned as expected.

I assume I have the gameDate test in the wrong place, but I can't figure it out.

Any suggestions on the query, or resources for me to learn more, will be gladly accepted.

Thanks.

Bill

Comment: So here's a suggestion: Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry do you keep that copied on your clipboard for questions like this?

Comment: @McAdam331 Yes. I got tired of writing out the same thing each time.

Comment: @Strawberry second time today I've come across it. Had a sensible chuckle.